# Jade/Pug: variable not showing in mixin

Tags: express, pug

I am new to Jade/Pug, and when I don't put the code with a variable in a mixin it works correctly, but when I use a mixin nothing is showing for the variable. I was hoping someone could explain how I can use mixins in variables correctly.

```
//-works
.teacher-wrapper
  .teacher-container
    each student in students
      .studentCardContainer.shadow90
        .studentInfoContainer
          .studentPhotoContainer
            .studentPhoto
              img(src="some_img.jpg")
            .studentName= student //<------ works
        .studentEmotionContainer
          div text
          div text
```

In this example I would like to use a mixin for each student, but the `= student` is not working. I tried `#{student}` as well, but it didn't work.

```
//- doesn't work
 .teacher-container
    each student in students
      +studentCard

    mixin studentCard
      .studentCardContainer.shadow90
        .studentInfoContainer
          .studentPhotoContainer
            .studentPhoto
              img(src="some_img.jpg")
            .studentName= student//<------ doesn't work ?
        .studentEmotionContainer
          div text
          div text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `student` as an argument to your mixin:

```
mixin studentCard(student)
  .studentCardContainer.shadow90
    .studentInfoContainer
      .studentPhotoContainer
        .studentPhoto
          img(src="some_img.jpg")
        .studentName= student
    .studentEmotionContainer
      div text
      div text

.teacher-container
  each student in students
    +studentCard(student)
```